# AS3: Combining counter (score) variable from multiple objects in different classes

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flashdevelop, class-variables

I am developing a fairly basic objective class space-shooter style flash game in AS3. The game originally contained 1 enemy target which had random variable parameters, such as speed and health, but the combined score counter remained predefined, one.

I have since expanded my game to where I have several enemy targets each having their own class, thus, they have their own variable parameter values. I also took the liberty of increasing the combined score, to reflect the difficulty of each enemy target.

The problem that I am running in to, is that my original line of code for combining the score counter is still set to "score++;", which just adds a value of 1 each time that "if statement" occurs.

My question, is how can I get my score counter to increase the score based on the value assigned for each respective class?

Here are a few bits of relevant code, with notes to help explain my view:

"If statement" (housed in my Level class) for when an enemy target is killed:

```
// if the bullet is touching the ship
if (MyMaths.hitTest(sh, bullets[bcount])) {
sh.health--; // lose 1 heath point
score++;
removeChild(bullets[bcount]); // remove the bullet from the screen
bullets.splice(bcount, 1); // remove the bullet from the list
}
```

Ship1 (housed in my Ship1 class) score value

```
public function Ship1() {
score=1; // set point value
}
```

Ship2 (housed in my Ship2 class) score value

```
public function Ship1() {
score=2; // set point value
}
```

Ship3 (housed in my Ship3 class) score value

```
public function Ship1() {
score=3; // set point value
}
```

I am just not sure if I would need to make a new function for combining the score value, and have my "score++;" pull from that, and how would I go about that?

I feel that this is a question that many fellow Objective-Oriented programmers would deem relevant, as combining a variable from multiple classes to a single counter is not as easy as it may seem. Also, this could be used in a wide range of other developer niches, apart from game developing -- creating a database of multiple models of computers in a network, and calculating a "total completed" field, after refreshing the workstations with a new OS or required software.

I really would appreciate anybody who could offer their expertise, opinion and/or words of encouragement.

Thank you very much,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a Singleton that **each** of the ships communicate with instead of doing it that way.

Whenever you increment the score:

```
ScoreManager.getInstance().incrementScore(ShipX.getScoreDelta())
```

Where `getScoreDelta()` would be reset to 0 after each collection.

Then when the game is done:

```
ScoreManager.getInstance().getCurrentScore();
```

Comment: That's a great idea. I will try that method. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not able to get that to work. It originally only needed to do "score++", because it was only calculating the single score. I changed the parameters on each individual .as, but they are still only adding 1 -- due to the script saying score++. Can you think of any other way of making if determine if it was ship1-3 and adding the correct value?

Comment: First of all, you should not not care about the individual scores. You should only keep track of the delta from the last time you collected. Unless each of them are calling ++ on the score, which is fine because it takes the current score and increases by one. It is not important what ship incremented it. Also what do you mean the "correct value" ? If you care about the individual score of each ship than have each ship object maintain its score, separate from the delta, assuming its not just +1 each time. Also try posting your new code.

Comment: JoxTraex, I really appreciate the effort. My buddy was able to help me out. We ended up using a switch case like so:

switch(sh.ship){
 case 1:
 score+=1;
 break;
 case 2:
 score+=2;
 break;
 case 3:
 score+=3;
 break;
}

I really appreciate your assistance. Take it easy!